# Optimal AWS EC2 instance-type for single-threaded Windows program

Tags: multithreading, optimization, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We am currently doing a scientific project that requires us to do some (relatively) heavy numerical simulations. The issue is that we are required to use a Windows-based program that only supports single threading.

Initially, we were under the assumption that a memory-optimized instance would be more cost-effective. Subsequently, we found out that the program doesn't utilize anything more than around 2GB of memory.

Looking at the table of compute-optimized instances on offer, does ECU refer to the overall computational performance? Or is it an indicator of performance for a single vCPU/core? Since the program doesn't run on multiple threads (and by extension multiple cores), this is an important question for us.

Comment: If it's single-threaded and never uses more than 2GB of memory, why do you need AWS? Any reasonably up-to-date desktop or laptop will do.

Comment: Each simulation will take a week at least, i'm trying to get the simulation time reduced (even by a small margin). Right now, the bottleneck seems to be the processor, so I'm wondering if a high-ECU EC2 instance will help.

Comment: The AWS processors are not fast processors. They are massively parallel. (lots of cores, low clock speed) Sounds like what you really need is an overclocked gaming/enthusiast computer.

Comment: That said, if you don't have such a machine, AWS is gong to be cheaper than getting a computer if it's just a one-time thing. Or if you can run multiple simulations at the same time...

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand that AWS compute-optimized instances have large numbers of vCPU (which doesn't help in my case). I'm just wondering if the individual vCPUs have higher performances for the higher tier instances... Based on your answer, I am assuming that ECU figures are overall performance across all vCPUs, hence pointless for my case?

Comment: While a single simulation cannot be run parallel, I could still use the multiple cores to run several simulations at the same time. Cost is not actually an issue, so may I will go with your idea of an overclocked machine!

Comment: I'm adding an answer for this, despite the question being quite old, since it comes up high in search results still

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain your software's performance will scale up with higher frequency cores then you'd want to look for instance types containing the `z` classifier.

As at Oct 2021 these are the [M5zn](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/m5/) and the [z1d](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/z1d/) instance types.